# Creating Class/Model so that a Json Return can cast into using DeserializeObject

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a 3rd party web service that i retrieve data from using VB.Net.
the web service has been through 3 phases in its time, SOAP as XML, Then REST as XML now finally REST as  Json. As well as changing the authentication methods to API Key and bearer.

So we are forced yet again to recode all out apps that post and get data from these web services, better yet they will be retiring all other methods soon.
So im hastily trying to get all our recording done.

One part im having trouble with is putting the json into a from im able to navigate in code (in the xml id just us as xml object and go through the nodes)

Ive read i have to create a object model that matches the Json structure in order to Deserialize into, but im having trouble making that model..
(i cant use Newtonsoft Json.NET either)

Below is the Json return for one Order, but its an array of 1 -1000 order per return..

I will continue fiddling myself, but was hoping one of you would be able to simply explain the class i have to build etc to get the job done!
(sorry ive removed most data just assume ""  is a string (as is most of the nulls) and ## are numbers)

```vb
{
  "outgoingOrders": {
    "order": [
      {
        "orderType": "",
        "orderSource": "",
        "espOrderNo": ###,
        "invoiceNumber": "",
        "externalReference": "",
        "date": "2017-08-23T23:51:02+0100",
        "customerCompany": null,
        "customerName": "",
        "customerAddress1": "",
        "customerAddress2": null,
        "customerAddress3": null,
        "customerCity": "",
        "customerCounty": "",
        "customerPostcode": "",
        "customerCountry": "",
        "customerEmail": "",
        "customerTelephone": "",
        "customerFax": null,
        "customerReference": null,
        "customerNotes": null,
        "deliveryCompany": null,
        "deliveryName": null,
        "deliveryAddress1": null,
        "deliveryAddress2": null,
        "deliveryAddress3": null,
        "deliveryCity": null,
        "deliveryCounty": null,
        "deliveryPostcode": null,
        "deliveryCountry": null,
        "deliveryTelephone": null,
        "shippingMethod": "",
        "shippingCost": ##.##,
        "insurance": 0.0,
        "discount": 0.0,
        "voucherCode": null,
        "orderTotal": ##.##,
        "paymentComplete": true,
        "payments": {
          "payment": [
            {
              "paymentMethod": "",
              "paymentReference": "",
              "paymentNotes": null,
              "paymentCCDetails": null,
              "paymentGateway": null,
              "payPalEmail": "",
              "payPalTransactionID": "",
              "payPalProtectionEligibility": true,
              "amount": ##.##,
              "paymentDate": "2017-08-23T00:00:00+0100",
              "paymentId": #####,
              "postedBatchId": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        "currencyCode": "",
        "sellerUsername": "",
        "sellerId": #,
        "courierProfileName": "",
        "buyerId": "",
        "orderItems": {
          "item": [
            {
              "webProductID": "",
              "stockNumber": "",
              "itemNumber": "",
              "productTitle": "",
              "quantity": #,
              "unitCost": #,
              "taxRate": #,
              "taxCode": null,
              "unitCostIncludesTax": "",
              "weight": 31000.0,
              "productFolderName": "#",
              "creditReason": null,
              "customMessage1": null,
              "customMessage2": null,
              "customMessage3": null,
              "locationId": ####,
              "supplierId": ##,
              "kitType": "",
              "kitMaster": "",
              "picked": false,
              "backOrder": false
            }
          ]
        },
        "storeId": null,
        "shipToStore": null,
        "orderCredits": null,
        "orderStatus": "",
        "flag1": "",
        "flag2": null,
        "courierName": "",
        "courierService": " ",
        "courierServiceCode": "",
        "fulfilmentType": "",
        "webOrderID": #####,
        "shippingDate": "2017-08-24T11:16:51+0100",
        "invoiceDate": "2017-08-23",
        "tradeSale": false,
        "courierTracking": ""
      }
    ]
  },"pageContext":{"timestamp":"2017-08-24T14:02:23+0100","hasMoreEntries":false,"pageSize":1}}
```

Comment: Copy the Json to the clipboard, then **Edit Menu**  -> **Paste Special**  -> **Paste Json as class**.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: "Copy the Json to the clipboard, then Edit Menu -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as class"

In what application?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Shame you can't use JSON.net, it makes this kind of thing so much easier.  If a full model is too problematic, you could try using Dictionaries to simplify it.

JSON is essentially a set of key/value pairs, so provided you get your nesting right for the object, you can often hold the whole thing in a few dictionaries.

In your case, nesting on "payments" and "orderItems" should do the trick.  Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: using Dictionaries just errors out, i think the json is either too complex or contains key words i.e. Date?
I made sure i increased the Serializer max length just in case it was too long..

            Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            jss.MaxJsonLength = 86753090

Comment: Its not too long, but it is not a simple set of key-value pairs.  `payments` and  `orderitems` are Types for instance.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] @GlenRichmond

Comment: it may be too long when you get 1000 orders in the array @Plutonix

Comment: Are you trying to deserialize as per the actual question posted or is this is 'follow up' question?  The posted json is only 2680 chars; I created **5000** order elements, serialized them then deserialized with no problem. @GlenRichmond

Comment: how did you serialise them? and with what.. im still trying to squirt the json into the class model.. and its the class model im having issues with..max orders ill ever get is 1000 per request as its paged at 1000 elements..

Answer (score 0):

I personally have created a JSON to XDocument module that takes in a JSON literal and then converts it to an XDocument object. This will allow you to query the desired nodes (which presumably represent properties) easily.

Here's the github: https://github.com/dday9/.NET-JSON-Transformer